# $scope.object is undefined angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

Can you please assist in finding why $Scope.notify is undefined, infact the other function is working totally fine.

services.js [ postmain and allresults are working fine but not notifyadd??]

```
            services.factory('PFactory', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
                alert("I am here service");

                return  {
                    postmain: $resource('/ngdemo/web/posts', {}, {
                        query: {method: 'GET', isArray: true },
                        create: {method: 'POST'}
                    }),
                    allresults: $resource('/ngdemo/web/posts/result/:tag', {}, {
                        query: {method: 'GET', params: {tag: '@tag'} },
                        create: {method: 'POST'}
                    }),
                    notifyadd: $resource('/ngdemo/web/notify', {}, {
                        query: {method: 'GET', isArray: true },
                        create: {method: 'POST'}
                    }),

                    allnotifications: $resource('/ngdemo/web/posts/result/:key', {}, {
                        query: {method: 'GET', params: {tag: '@key'} },
                        create: {method: 'POST'}
                    })};
            }]);
```

CONTROLLER.js

```
            app.controller('MyCtrl2', ['$scope', 'PFactory', '$location', function ($scope, PFactory, $location) {

                $scope.createPost = function () {

                    PFactory.postmain.create($scope.UserPost)
                    $scope.allposts.push($scope.UserPost);

                    $scope.UserPost = "";

                }

                $scope.notify = function () {
                   console.log("in notify" + $scope.Notify.secEmail);
                    PFactory.notifyadd.create($scope.Notify)

                }

            }]);
```

HTML file:

```
            <form role="form">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-4">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <input type="text" ng-model='Notify.secEmail'
                                                       placeholder="Email of the person who can help?" class="form-control"
                                                       ></div>
                                        </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-4">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <input type="text" ng-model="Notify.message"
                                                               placeholder="Enter a Message or Phone number" class="form-control"
                                                               >
                                                       <!-- <input type="hidden" ng-model="Notify.loggedInEmail" ng-value="{{ result.first_name }}" />
                                                        <input type="hidden" ng-model="Notify.postId" ng-value="{{ post.id }}" />
                                                        <input type="hidden" ng-model="Notify.destEmail" ng-value="{{ post.userEmail }}" />-->
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                                            <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="notify()" type="button">
                                                Notify
                                            </button>
                                            <!--<input type="submit" ng-click='notify()' value="Notify"
                                                   class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-sm" tabindex="7">-->
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
```

ERROR I am getting is:

```
Error: $scope.Notify is undefined $scope.notify@http://pingle.com:8080/ngdemo/js/controllers.js:213
```

Same works with postmain create function but not with Notify!! Any idea?

Comment: I see the function `notify()` but not the object `Notify` - where has it been defined? As the error states, the object is undefined - which is correct. I can't see any definition of it, yet you use its properties in your view (and also seem to submit an HTTP POST request using that object)

Comment: I am capturing the value entered in input text as "<input type="text" ng-model="Notify.message"", Notify is my java object. and when function notify is called, it says undefined, however if you see same is working fine for createPost method and it doesnt throw any error for "UserPost"

Comment: Actually this view code is under ng-repeat "<ul ng-repeat="post in allposts" class="timeline">"! I just tried above code outside ng-repeat and it worked. is there any issue with objects and calling new post inside ng-repeat which I am missing?

Comment: Just define $scope.Notify in your controller.

Comment: I tried with    $scope.notify = function () {          
       console.log("in notify" + $scope.Notify.secEmail);
        PFactory.notifyadd.create($scope.Notify)
        $scope.Notify = "";
    }

Comment: but still not wokring, can u ples lemme knw how to do? I am totally new! Strange is, when I put the same code outside ng-repeat, its working! :(

Comment: Include the repeat in your template and tidy it up, it's a common curtsey when asking for help to at least make your code samples look sane. Two people have already told you it's because the Notify object doesn't exist on $scope. You need to define it in the controller. `$scope.Notify = { message:null, secEmail:null };` If this is all in a look though you need to be binding to the loop variable otherwise every form will be bound to the same instance of Notify.